# Is it possible to execute commands after capistrano fetches files from Git, but before deploy_via?

Tags: coffeescript, sass, capistrano

I have a PHP Zend Framework project, with Sass and Coffeescript files. For deployment I use Capistrano version 2.15 The deployment:update_code task fetches the right Git code from bitbucket.org, but also directly copies the code to the remote server.

Between those steps I would like to execute command to compile sass and coffeescript files. Is this possible or is the only option to do this on the remote server?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Pieter